# add comment programmatically to xml

Tags: java, xml-parsing

Is there any way to programmatically comment a particular child in XML? 
My requirement is I need to find out the attribute value from the xml.If that values exists I need to comment that particular child itself which the attribute belongs.
eg:

```
<Company>
 <employee name="John">
   <dept id="Purchase"></dept>
 </employee>
</company>
```

so here if I search for dept id "purchase" if it is found then the employee John should be able to add comment.

any idea? I am using jdom parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the JavaCode that will add a comment to the document itself:

```
Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
Comment comment = doc.createComment("This is a comment");
element.getParentNode().insertBefore(comment, element);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new comment nodes using [Document.createComment()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#createComment%28java.lang.String%29) and insert them into your DOM tree using e.g. [Node.insertBefore(Node, Node)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#insertBefore%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20org.w3c.dom.Node%29).